# React Native elevation on the top of View

Tags: android, react-native, elevation

I need to set shadow on the top of View, for iOS I use **shadowOffset** and it works fine but for Android in the docs says to use **elevation** and now my problem is that elevation set shadow only under View but I need to shadow was on top of View. How can I do it? I still can't find the solution

```
tabBarOptions: {
    showLabel: false,
    inactiveTintColor: '#BBBBBB',
    activeTintColor: '#D36221',
    style: {
        height: 50,
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: -13
        },
        shadowColor: 'black',
        shadowOpacity: 0.2,
        shadowRadius: 27,
        borderTopWidth: 0,
        elevation: 2,
    }
}
```

Comment: did you got the answer for this?

Comment: To solve this problem you can use react-native-shadow library which allows you to control shadow on android as on ios